# After read.csv content looks really confusing

Tags: r

After using `read.csv()` the content of my file does not looks very complicated. I tried some functions and steps but can not make it work. Here is how the first few rows look in the console:

```
read.csv("TestR.csv", sep=",", header=T)
```

Console output:

```
   FragebogenID.Datum.Uhrzeit.FragebogenNr.Standort.Befrager.Zweirad.Geschlecht.Alter.Bildung.PLZ.Ort.Land.VerweigererIn.VerweigererOut.Ausgangspunkt.Anreise.Aufenthaltsdauer.Radfahren.Wandern.Joggen.Spazierengehen.Pilze.Nationalparkveranstaltung.Tierbe ...
0001;08.06.19;11:01;1;Parkplatz Deffernik;Carina Kronschnabl;2;2;69;2;77736;Zell;Deutschland;;;3;4;5;1;4;5;3;3;2;2;;4;15:00;40;1;1;1;4;5;1;;1;;;;1;71;2;;;;;;;;;;;;;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
0002;08.06.19;11:40;2;Parkplatz Deffernik;Carina Kronschnabl;2;1;44;5;;;Deutschland;4;4;;1;4;1;2;5;3;2;5;5;5;;2;11:45;25;1;11;6;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;Radwege schlechter beschildert                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   kein Netz im Vergleich zum Sumava Nationalpark
0003;08.06.19;12:20;3;Parkplatz Deffernik;Carina Kronschnabl;2;1;62;6;93180;Deuerling;Deutschland;3;4;;2;1;3;1;4;1;4;4;5;5;;8;18:00;60;650;1;1;4;5;1;;1;;;;2;60;2;;;;;;;;;;;;;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
0004;08.06.19;12:35;4;Parkplatz Deffernik;Carina Kronschnabl;4;2;34;7;81379;München;Deutschland;;;2;4;3;4;4;4;4;5;5;5;Schwimmen: 4;5;14:00;70;700;6;4;1;;3;;;;1;72;4;2;60;4;1;66;4;;;;;;;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
0005;08.06.19;13:00;5;Parkplatz Deffernik;Carina Kronschnabl;4;2;37;7;94227;Zwiesel;Deutschland;;;1;4;1;1;1;1;1;3;2;4;;3;17:00;50;1000;11;4;1;;1;;;;1;39;4;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: it looks like in your file the columns are separated by ";" and not by ",". can you try running again with `read.csv("TestR.csv", sep=";", header=T)`

Comment: Even though the data seems to se separated by ":", I think the header es separated by ".". Did using `sep = ";"`worked?

Comment: not sure the part about the headers is true. I am suspecting `read.csv` is only detecting one column (since it does not find any ",") and then the default behaviour of `read.csv` (`check.names = TRUE`) will replace special characters with "."

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the header line (with the column names) has a different field separator than the data lines below.

So, I suggest a stepwise approach:

1. Read in the first line of the file and separate the column names
2. Read in the whole file except the first line using `";"` as field separator
3. Rename the columns of the data.frame

This is what I would do using my preferred tools:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
# read header and separate
hdr <- fread("TestR.csv", sep = "", nrows = 1L, header = FALSE)[, V1] %>% 
  strsplit("\\.") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  trimws()
# read data and rename columns
dat <- fread("TestR.csv", skip = 1L, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE) %>% 
  setnames(seq_along(hdr), hdr)
dat
```

> ```
>    FragebogenID    Datum Uhrzeit FragebogenNr            Standort           Befrager Zweirad Geschlecht Alter Bildung   PLZ
> 1:            1 08.06.19   11:01            1 Parkplatz Deffernik Carina Kronschnabl       2          2    69       2 77736
> 2:            2 08.06.19   11:40            2 Parkplatz Deffernik Carina Kronschnabl       2          1    44       5    NA
> 3:            3 08.06.19   12:20            3 Parkplatz Deffernik Carina Kronschnabl       2          1    62       6 93180
> 4:            4 08.06.19   12:35            4 Parkplatz Deffernik Carina Kronschnabl       4          2    34       7 81379
> 5:            5 08.06.19   13:00            5 Parkplatz Deffernik Carina Kronschnabl       4          2    37       7 94227
>          Ort        Land VerweigererIn VerweigererOut Ausgangspunkt Anreise Aufenthaltsdauer Radfahren Wandern Joggen
> 1:      Zell Deutschland            NA             NA             3       4                5         1       4      5
> 2:           Deutschland             4              4            NA       1                4         1       2      5
> 3: Deuerling Deutschland             3              4            NA       2                1         3       1      4
> 4:  MÃ¼nchen Deutschland            NA             NA             2       4                3         4       4      4
> 5:   Zwiesel Deutschland            NA             NA             1       4                1         1       1      1
>    Spazierengehen Pilze Nationalparkveranstaltung Tierbe                   V28   V29  V30 V31 V32 V33 V34 V35 V36 V37 V38 V39
> 1:              3     3                         2      2               4 15:00    40    1   1   1   4   5   1  NA   1  NA  NA
> 2:              3     2                         5      5            5 NA     2 11:45   25   1  11   6   1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 3:              1     4                         4      5            5 NA     8 18:00   60 650   1   1   4   5   1  NA   1  NA
> 4:              4     5                         5      5 Schwimmen: 4  5 14:00    70  700   6   4   1  NA   3  NA  NA  NA   1
> 5:              1     3                         2      4               3 17:00    50 1000  11   4   1  NA   1  NA  NA  NA   1
>    V40 V41 V42 V43 V44 V45 V46 V47 V48 V49 V50 V51 V52 V53 V54
> 1:  NA   1  71   2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 2:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 3:  NA  NA   2  60   2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 4:  72   4   2  60   4   1  66   4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 5:  39   4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                V55
> 1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
> 2: Radwege schlechter beschildert                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   kein Netz im Vergleich zum Sumava Nationalpark
> 3:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
> 4:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
> 5:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>    V56 V57
> 1:  NA  NA
> 2:  NA  NA
> 3:  NA  NA
> 4:  NA  NA
> 5:  NA  NA
> ```

#### Finetuning

There is some more finetuning possible to avoid empty column headers and to collapse white space inside  character columns:

```
hdr <- fread("TestR.csv", sep = "", nrows = 1L, header = FALSE)[, V1] %>% 
  strsplit("\\.") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  trimws() %>% 
  ifelse(. == "", paste0("V", seq_along(.)), .) # avoid empty column names
# read data and rename columns
dat <- fread("TestR.csv", skip = 1L, header = FALSE, fill = TRUE) %>% 
  setnames(seq_along(hdr), hdr)
# collapse white space
chr_cols <- names(dat)[sapply(dat, class) == "character"]
dat[, (chr_cols) := lapply(.SD, stringr::str_squish), .SDcols = chr_cols]
dat
```

> ```
>    FragebogenID    Datum Uhrzeit FragebogenNr            Standort           Befrager Zweirad Geschlecht Alter Bildung   PLZ
> 1:            1 08.06.19   11:01            1 Parkplatz Deffernik Carina Kronschnabl       2          2    69       2 77736
> 2:            2 08.06.19   11:40            2 Parkplatz Deffernik Carina Kronschnabl       2          1    44       5    NA
> 3:            3 08.06.19   12:20            3 Parkplatz Deffernik Carina Kronschnabl       2          1    62       6 93180
> 4:            4 08.06.19   12:35            4 Parkplatz Deffernik Carina Kronschnabl       4          2    34       7 81379
> 5:            5 08.06.19   13:00            5 Parkplatz Deffernik Carina Kronschnabl       4          2    37       7 94227
>          Ort        Land VerweigererIn VerweigererOut Ausgangspunkt Anreise Aufenthaltsdauer Radfahren Wandern Joggen
> 1:      Zell Deutschland            NA             NA             3       4                5         1       4      5
> 2:           Deutschland             4              4            NA       1                4         1       2      5
> 3: Deuerling Deutschland             3              4            NA       2                1         3       1      4
> 4:  MÃ¼nchen Deutschland            NA             NA             2       4                3         4       4      4
> 5:   Zwiesel Deutschland            NA             NA             1       4                1         1       1      1
>    Spazierengehen Pilze Nationalparkveranstaltung Tierbe          V26 V27   V28   V29  V30 V31 V32 V33 V34 V35 V36 V37 V38 V39
> 1:              3     3                         2      2                4 15:00    40    1   1   1   4   5   1  NA   1  NA  NA
> 2:              3     2                         5      5            5  NA     2 11:45   25   1  11   6   1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 3:              1     4                         4      5            5  NA     8 18:00   60 650   1   1   4   5   1  NA   1  NA
> 4:              4     5                         5      5 Schwimmen: 4   5 14:00    70  700   6   4   1  NA   3  NA  NA  NA   1
> 5:              1     3                         2      4                3 17:00    50 1000  11   4   1  NA   1  NA  NA  NA   1
>    V40 V41 V42 V43 V44 V45 V46 V47 V48 V49 V50 V51 V52 V53 V54
> 1:  NA   1  71   2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 2:  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 3:  NA  NA   2  60   2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 4:  72   4   2  60   4   1  66   4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 5:  39   4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
>                                                                              V55 V56 V57
> 1:                                                                                NA  NA
> 2: Radwege schlechter beschildert kein Netz im Vergleich zum Sumava Nationalpark  NA  NA
> 3:                                                                                NA  NA
> 4:                                                                                NA  NA
> 5:
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the tools you suggested but it doesn't work. I don't know why but there are always defaults. And my R version on Mac doesn't know "fread". Are there different versions?

Comment: I replaced "," with ";" and it worked, but now it only shows 18 of 285 rows, do you know why? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, these are _my_ preferred tools. The approach can also be implemented using other packages.

Comment: Concerning `fread()`: What version of `data.table` have you installed on your computer?

Comment: Concerning the missing rows: This is difficult to answer without inspecting the data file in detail. The fact that the header row and the data rows use different characters to separate fields may indicate issues with the consistency and integrity of the data file in general.